# How to start training from different epoch Mask R-CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am training the Mask R-CNN [model](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py).

I saved the weights after training for 2 epochs the 'head' and I want to continue from epoch three. But the model.train() function does not have **initial_epoch** argument as model.fit in a Sequential model for example.

I have the following code but if I run it with the loaded weights it starts from the first epoch and I don't want that:

```
EPOCHS = [1, 3, 5, 8]  

model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
                learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE,
                epochs = EPOCHS[1],
                layers = 'all',
                augmentation = augmentation)
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what is the substitute for initial_epoch in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first 2 epochs of fitting your model changed its weights. So, when you call `fit` once again the model will continue training. Your progress won't lost

Comment: But I don't call .fit. I call .train. I could not find if there is any difference. And when I call .train I start from epoch 1 again. This is what I wonder if this is the same first epoch as the one I trained or it is just like training a new model from scratch. I am sorry if this sounds stupid but I need to understand it.

Comment: The one who doesn't ask questions is stupid. Look inside `train`. There is a call `fit_generator` which works as `fit` now (with new version of tensorflow). Every time you call fit, you'll see information about fitting starting from epoch 1. But it doesn't mean you're a retrain the model. By calling `fit` twice you will just continue the training process

Comment: I would recommend you to build your models using only keras to understand, how does it works

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very useful.